Differential amplifier Q point
I'm looking for a way to solve the Q point of this amplifier
I found this set of equation :
EQ1: I=Ic3(1+1/Beta3)+Ic4(1+1/Beta4)
EQ2: Ic1/Beta1+Ic2/Beta2=Ic4-Ic2
EQ3: Iout=Ic3-Ic1
EQ4: Ic1(1+1/Beta1)*RE1+Vbe1-Vbe2-Ic2(1+1/Beta2)*RE2=0
I have those variables : Ic3, Ic4, Ic1, Ic2, Iout
My problem is I can't find the last equation to solve the system...
I hope you could help me, thanks for your help

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Where did you find the equations? How does the reader know they are valid or appropriate?

KCL, KVL laws and transistor law : Ic=Beta*Ib. Do you see other things I can add to better understand the equations ?

This circuit is not properly biased because no current will flow through Q3&Q4 collectors.
The Q3&Q4 Vbe limits the room for mirror to about 0.6V (too few).
Do it like in Lm358 where additional bjts are added in front of Q3&Q4 to get 1.2V room for mirror.

Source: ti.com
Or supply the bottom of your circuit with negative voltage.

You're right, there are +/-15 supplies. See the correction.

Your circuit can be simplified and made pretty easy to quickly guess about:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that I've started out dividing in half the current source at the top, half for each side. Tentatively, this flows all the way through the current mirror BJTs, as well.
There's an obvious error to that. The base currents for both \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are stolen from \$Q_4\$'s collector current. So \$Q_2\$'s collector current will be about (assuming \$\beta\approx 100\$ as a guess) \$20\:\mu\text{A}\$ less than expected (from \$Q_4\$'s collector.) So \$Q_2\$'s collector current will be a little bit short. This means \$Q_1\$'s collector current will also be short by about that same amount. This leaves \$20\:\mu\text{A}\$ for your \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$ resistor.
But there's another error now in that thinking. That's because with only \$20\:\mu\text{A}\$ through \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$, that only makes up \$200\:\text{mV}\$ across \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$. And that means \$Q_1\$ is being pulled into saturation. This means a little less collector current in \$Q_1\$ and that difference, \$I_x\$, will be added to the current going through \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$. Perhaps an extra few microamps?
So I'd guess that \$Q_1\$'s collector will be more positive than \$-14.8\:\text{V}\$. But not by a lot. So \$-14.8\:\text{V}\le V_x \le -14.7\:\text{V}\$.
Let's give it a whirl in LTspice:

Hmm. Yeah. Looks close enough for a back of an envelope calculation. I over-estimated the \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ for the PNP BJTs. But by only \$30\:\text{mV}\$.
I also under-estimated \$\beta\$. But I did that because I was expecting saturation (looking ahead.) If you increase \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$ by a factor of 10, say, then neither of the current mirror BJTs are saturated (good) and the base currents stolen from \$Q_4\$'s collector current will be closer to the expected amount based on a higher \$\beta\$ value -- perhaps half what I estimated earlier since then \$\beta\approx 200\$, instead. Without saturation for \$Q_1\$, I'd expect the combined two base currents (on the order now of \$2\times 5\:\mu\text{A}=10\:\mu\text{A}\$) to be the current in the new, larger-valued \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$. So that would be about \$1\:\text{V}\$ drop across \$R_{_\text{OUT}}\$ and now I'd guess \$V_x\approx -14\:\text{V}\$.
Let's see:

Again, fairly predictable with a simple piece of paper and only a few thoughts to put together.

Hello periblepsis and thanks a lot for your explanations. it's a very interesting way to solve this circuit. For current I'm ok with you and yes for the example I put the output resistor (input impédance of the second stage which is a common emitter, but yes 10k is very low), my problem was to solve it with KVL, KCL law and Beta for transistor but I can't see what is the last equation in my eq system to solve it... could you please help me to find the last equation ?

@exolune The collector voltage for shared Q1/Q3 isn't determinable without getting into non-linear models. It's not amenable to on-paper KCL/KVL solution, if you remove ROUT from the circuit, or if you make ROUT very much larger than the 100k I finally applied (which was the largest value I would dare to use to make the collector voltage predictable on a piece of paper's worth of math.) The fuller Ebers-Moll model, the 3rd version that includes the Early Effect, or the Gummel-Poon (modified or otherwise), can do it though. I also made assumptions about Vbe, while they are functions of Ic.

Thanks a lot for your explanations. It's clear for me now. For Ebers-Moll model with early effect, do you means this : Ic=Isexp(Ve/Vt)(1+Vce/VA) ?
